# Optimization of three single-variable functions by varying them at the same time

Tags: optimization, matlab

I have a target dependent variable "efficiency" ,$F$, and its output (from 0 to 1) can be affected by three parameters: $F(\gamma, \epsilon, \alpha)$. The baseline case values for these parameters are: $$\gamma=0.0073, \epsilon=0.3, \alpha=0.02$$

I have identified the equation for each parameter:
$$F(\gamma, 0.3, 0.02)=-972176(\gamma)^4+55948(\gamma)^3-1212(\gamma)^2+12.2(\gamma)+0.71$$
$$F(0.0073,\epsilon, 0.02)=7.76(\epsilon)^4-17.62(\epsilon)^3+11.34(\epsilon)^2-2.77(\epsilon)+0.97$$
$$F(0.0073, 0.3, \alpha)=-11535(\alpha)^4+1061(\alpha)^3-39.5(\alpha)^2+0.0055(\alpha)+0.76$$

All functions are 4th-degree polynomials. The purpose here is to maximize efficiency $(F)$ while varying the three independent variables at the same time, so we can find the right values for $\gamma, \epsilon, \alpha$ that maximize efficiency $(F)$.

I would like to do this on Matlab, but I don't even know what kind of optimization is this. Multi objective is not, because there is only one target function. Multivariable is not either, because the three equations are single-variable each. So I do not know how to look in Matlab docs.

Please help

Comment: What do you mean by baseline values of the three variables? You will need a representation of $F(\gamma, \epsilon, \alpha)$ as a function of these three variables. Right now you have three functions which are different. Some description of what you are modelling might be helpful

Comment: In general, I’m only asking how to optimize (maximum) the objective function F. I don’t have a single multi-variable equation, I can only obtain the equation from varying each parameter at a time.

Comment: The objective function needs to be well defined for you to optimize it. If you don't have a multi-variable function, what use will you have for the optimal $\gamma, \epsilon, \alpha$